# How to add and save RSS Feed in Split-View based app in ipad

Tags: objective-c, ipad, rss, uisplitviewcontroller, feed

I created split-view based app ipad which is retrieving the RSS Feeds and content. Now i want to add one more RSS Feed to my Feeds list and save. Then show the content in Detailview.
Is it possible to add and save RSS Feed.?

Thanks,

Chakradhar.

Comment: Of course it is possible, but we cannot help you without more detail. Are you using Core Data?

Comment: @sosborn  i just pass the xml parsing to the Apple blog site and get the titles at left and content at right . now add rss feed to that list